# MySQL Workbench: "ssl is required but the server doesn't support it"

Tags: mysql-workbench, ssl

I'm having trouble finding answers with various Internet and Google searches for MySQL Workbench issue I'm experiencing.

I have not found any answers on how to make this work again.

Here's the MySQL Workbench error I'm having issues troubleshooting which I need help

> mysql workbench failed to connect at localhost:3306 with user root ssl
> connection error: ssl is required but the server doesn't support it

Comment: A couple of notes: `localhost` is always the computer the command is running on, so I'm not certain that encryption serves much purpose. SSL requires a certificate be installed on the server in question. See if you can modify the configuration in mysqlworkbench to connect to the server without encryption/SSL.

Comment: For Windows Client, if you don't have the SSL Option Required = No,  after MySQL Workbench update, check @AntonioMariaSanchez answer.

Comment: Workbench V8.0.28 is now available and fixes this issue

Answer (score 21, accepted):

### Configure MySQL Workbench to not require SSL encryption

If you get the **MySQL Workbench** error of "***SSL connection error: SSL is required but the server doesn't support it***" then you likely just need to change a setting that's defined within the **MySQL Connections** within MySQL Workbench.

[image]

From the **MySQL Connections** screen click on the little wrench icon [image] to the right to bring up **Manage Server Connections** window.

[image]

From the **Manage Server Connections** window click on the "MySQL Connection" that is giving you this error, then from the **SSL** tab you will want to ensure the **Use SSL** field has a value of **If available** so it only uses SSL if it's available or else it'll connect without SSL encryption.

[image]

Press the **Test Connection** option from the bottom of the **Manage Server Connections** window after you make the to confirm the error goes away.

---

### **Continued Trouble**

**Update:** Firstly, downgrading to version `8.0.26` brings back the `No` and `If available` options for the `Use SSL` field. They're removed in version `8.0.27`. You can find older versions here of MySQL Workbench here: [MySQL Product Archives](https://downloads.mysql.com/archives/workbench)

If you continue to have trouble you might set the **Use SSL** field to a value of **No** and also ensure all the SSL fields below that are blank and then test the connection again.

[image]

Comment: This answer will only work in some case uses. My case use was different. I was trying to use TLD SSL to connect MYSQL which is more difficult.

Comment: I don't have Use SSl "No" here, any other solution?

Comment: @KarimSamir Downgrading to 8.0.26 brings back the No and If available options. They're removed in 8.0.27. You can find older versions here: https://downloads.mysql.com/archives/workbench/

Comment: @MagnusWinter I looked over the [release notes](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/relnotes/workbench/en/news-8-0.html) a few versions back and I didn't see anything obvious indicating they are taking those options away. Do you know if they changed this intentionally as per a previous release mentioning deprecating the function with those options? Just curious if it's a bug with version `8.0.27` or if this has been a change that's been known to be coming. And I added an update to my post per this comment, so thank you!

Comment: why dnt they just leave the option there... sometimes things can be so annoying, PS ** thanks @ITThugNinja

Comment: For Windows Client, if you don't have the SSL Option Required = No, after MySQL Workbench update, check @AntonioMariaSanchez answer.

Answer (score 23):

At least in MySQL Workbench community edition 8.0.27 no Use SSL option is not available. You could define useSSL parameter described in previous answer, in the Advance tab:

[image]

Comment: This is the more easy solution to the problem on Windows

Comment: The option useSSL=0 worked for me.
Windows 11 
Workbench 8.0.27

Comment: Much better option than downgrading.

Comment: I used, but when I click in test conexion everything ok, but when I close and try to connect show me error and if edit conexion again the useSSL=0 don't appear (I use Linux Ubuntu 20.04) and workbench 8.0.27

Comment: On Linux, Workbench 8.0.27 does *not* have the option to make SSL optional.

Comment: After adding the useSSL=0, it was not saving it. So just used it in runtime when defining the connection for migration and it worked on windows 10. Thank you.

Comment: excellent solution.  i have to wonder why our good friends at mysql-workbench have not included this in a checkbox or something like that?   thank you for answering this.

Answer (score 17):

You can bring back the old SSL options in `8.0.27`:

- Close MySQL Workbench
- Go to you MySQL Workbench install folder (p.e. `C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Workbench 8.0 CE`)
- open the file `modules/data/mysql_rdbms_info.xml`
- replace all occurrences of

  - `>2|Require,3|Require and Verify CA,4|Require and Verify Identity`
  - with `>0|No,1|If available,2|Require,3|Require and Verify CA,4|Require and Verify Identity`

Now you have the old options back:
[image]

Comment: Same file in linux relies at `/usr/share/mysql-workbench/modules/data/mysql_rdbms_info.xml`

Comment: MAC Os - Open in the Finder with Right-click in the Applications/MySQLWorkbench - Show Package contents and edit the file Resources/modules/data/mysql_rdbms_info.xml

Comment: Worked for me on Win 10. Thank you

Comment: This is a much better solution than downgrading to a possible unsafe older Version!

Answer (score 6):

In workbench 8.0.27 if under the SSL tab you don't see the option **No**, edit file `$HOME/.mysql/workbench/connections.xml`, look for the connection that you want to disable ssl, and find `<value type="int" key="useSSL">2</value>` set it to 0, that will disable ssl for that connection.

Comment: Note that this does not seem to work on windows. When after editing `~\AppData\Roaming\MySQL\Workbench\connections.xml`, when a connection is attempted, the value is changed back to a 2.

Comment: Sorry about Windows, I have never test it on it as I'm a Linux user, but good catch. Thanks

Answer (score 5):

[image: add useSSL=0 in advanced tab]

add useSSL=0 in advanced tab this worked for me in win 10

Answer (score 1):

windows10, Workbench 8.0.27
close the MySQL Workbench (important, otherwise it will overwrite the edit)
in `~\AppData\Roaming\MySQL\Workbench\connections.xml`
set `<value type="int" key="useSSL">0</value>` and save.

DO not touch the Edit Connections for this connection, it would overwrite the 0 by a 2

Comment: this solution worked for me

Answer (score 1):

[A bug in MySQL Workbench 8.0.27](https://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=105462). Fixed for 8.0.28 whenever that gets released. Details at link.

Answer (score -1):

i was facing same problem since last 3 days but i realize that if new version of workbench don't have NO/IF AVAILABLE option but we can solve it through go to ADVANCE  and write on others: useSSL=0 and remain keep same.
It will solve but with attention/warning.

Comment: Hi there and welcome to the DBA.SE community. Your answer doesn't seem to add any additional solutions other than those already provided.